# FullCalendar highlight custom button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have the following custom button,

```
todayBtn: {
    text: <p>todayButton</p>,
    click: () => {
        this.changeView("resourceTimeGridDay")
    }
 }
```

When I load the FullCalendar component for the first time, I want the custom button to be active/highlighted.

I couldn't find any resource that helps me do this.

Comment: Can you add link to live working example? Eg Codepen, jsfiddle.

Comment: By active, do you mean focused? Or what precisely?

Comment: P.S. You don't need a custom button to show the resourceTimeGridDay view. Your button's name is also misleading - this isn't a "today" button...it will not change the calendar's date to today.